# Bob is playing a video game that has 7 levels. He starts at level 1, and has a probability p1 of reaching level 2.

Tags: probability

Bob is playing a video game that has 7 levels. He starts at level 1, and has a probability $p_1$ of reaching level 2. In general, given that he reaches level j, he has probability $p_j$ of reaching level j + 1, for 1 ≤ j ≤ 6. Let X be the highest level that he reaches. Find the PMF of X (in terms of $p_1$,··· ,$p_6$).

- We did not have time to go over this section in class because we ran out of time. I was thinking the PMF could be P(X=x)=($p_1$)($p_2$)...($p_{x-1}$). I am extremely confused, any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there. Since $x$ is the highest level he reaches, he must also *fail to reach the next level*. That has a probability of $1-p_x$.

e.g. suppose $3$ is the highest level he reaches. That means that he has cleared levels $1$ and $2$, but failed to advance to $4$. Hence the probability of this happening is $P(X = 3) = (p_1)(p_2)(1-p_3)$.

Therefore in general, for $1 \le x < 7$:

$$P(X=x) = (p_1)(p_2)\dots(p_{x-1})(1-p_x)$$

and for $X=7$, since there are no more levels to reach, the probability is simply

$$P(X=7)=(p_1)(p_2)\dots(p_6)$$